Problem when try to access serial port of ZTE cellular modem
I'm trying to access the serial port of ZTE MF831 cellular modem.
I can access the serial port from Windows using the driver "ZTE Proprietary USB Modem" (modem.sys, ZTEusbmdm6k.sys)
But I can't access it from the raspberry pi, I've tried:
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600

but i can't input anything and there is no output, I've also tried to read/write using cat/echo to /dev/ttyUSB0 without success
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 19d2:0016 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM ZTE Wireless Ethernet Adapter

dmesg
[13336096.289113] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[13336096.423536] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=0016, bcdDevice=52.45
[13336096.423565] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13336096.423579] usb 1-1.3: Product: ZTE Wireless Ethernet Adapter
[13336096.423589] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[13336096.444144] option 1-1.3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[13336096.444559] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0


Update

sudo journalctl --follow
Oct 03 01:00:59 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Oct 03 01:00:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1423164]: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Oct 03 01:00:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1423164]: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Oct 03 01:00:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1423172]: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Oct 03 01:00:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1423172]: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Oct 03 01:01:13 raspberrypi ModemManager[656]: <warn>  [ttyUSB0/probe] failed to parse QCDM version info command result: -7
Oct 03 01:01:13 raspberrypi ModemManager[656]: <warn>  [ttyUSB0/probe] failed to parse QCDM version info command result: -7
Oct 03 01:01:13 raspberrypi ModemManager[656]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3] creating modem with plugin 'zte' and '1' ports
Oct 03 01:01:13 raspberrypi ModemManager[656]: <warn>  [plugin/zte] could not grab port ttyUSB0: Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB0', unhandled port type
Oct 03 01:01:13 raspberrypi ModemManager[656]: <warn>  [base-manager] couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3': Failed to find primary AT port

usb-devices
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 15 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=19d2 ProdID=0016 Rev=52.45
S:  Manufacturer=ZTE,Incorporated
S:  Product=ZTE Wireless Ethernet Adapter
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  10 Ivl=32ms
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=84(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  10 Ivl=32ms

permissions
$ id -a
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),20(dialout)
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Oct  3 01:45 /dev/ttyUSB0

I've also tried to disable ModemManager and then try to connect using minicom but i get the same result

Try different speeds, including 115200. Things are sent, but minicom doesn't have local echo by default, so you'll see nothing on screen unless remote end echoes it.

I've tried different speeds, with stty, i got this error stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: unable to perform all requested operations on all of them except on 9600, regarding minicom echo - AT\r should return OK but it doesn't

Many device access problems are permission problems, and can be resolved through group membership changes.
You can find the device name by watching sudo journalctl --follow as you connect your device (if you hsve journalctl). OR ls -1 -l /dev >dev.before, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, ls -1 -l /dev >dev.after;diff /dev/{before,after}.
Specifically, if ls -l  shows that the group permissions (the second "rwx" triplet) is "rw" (e.g."-rw-rw----"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant rw access.
Here's how:
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/YourDevice"
device="/dev/ttyUSB0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)

This allows you membership in the group (as a member of the secondary group) that can rw the device, but there is one more step.
To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at login time.
To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)  

See man newgrp.

Thanks, but i was already in the correct group, however I got more info from the command journalctl that you suggested, I'll post an update now
